# In ionic framework & cordova-plugin-camera pictures taken with camera are being rotated 90 degrees anti clockwise in app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am working on Ionic framework for my hybrid app and using Cordova, I am facing an issue with the pictures taken with camera in both ios and android. When a picture is taken using the device camera in portrait mode it's orientation is being changed automatically. the issue is in both mobile app's (ios & android) and in web (safari & chrome). I used cordova-plugin-camera in application and this is the code in UIImage+CropScaleOrientation.m file in plugin ios code where the rotation for ios is taking place

```
(UIImage*)imageCorrectedForCaptureOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)imageOrientation
    {
        float rotation_radians = 0;
        bool perpendicular = false;

        switch (imageOrientation) {
            case UIImageOrientationUp :
                rotation_radians = 0.0;
                break;

            case UIImageOrientationDown:
                rotation_radians = M_PI; // don't be scared of radians, if you're reading this, you're good at math
                break;

            case UIImageOrientationRight:
                rotation_radians = M_PI_2;
                perpendicular = true;
                break;

            case UIImageOrientationLeft:
                rotation_radians = -M_PI_2;
                perpendicular = true;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
     }
```

[this is how i captured the image with device camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdLBd.jpg)

and after selecting (capture), It changes its orientation and in webview also both in chrome(android) and in safari(iphone)
[picture orientation getting chaned in web also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLF3S.jpg)

this is my first **stack overflow** question so pardon my mistakes, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For fix it on iOS:

```
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { 
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        correctOrientation: true,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
```

The `correctOrientation: true` instruction is the key.
Hope this help!

Comment: It also works for android too. Reference : [GitHub Page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameracameraoptions--object) See `correctOrientation`